# UWP HttpClient store the cookie until the app is unisntalled

Tags: cookies, win-universal-app, httpclient, store

I login in my app and get response cookie and set. Then I close the app. When I restart the app, my cookie is cleared. I have to login again.

How can I store the cookie until I uninstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually read and save the returned cookie and then restore it when the app starts again!

To read all cookies (assuming you added a `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` and that is represented by `filter`) use this:

```cs
var cookieCollection = filter.CookieManager.GetCookies(resourceUri);
```

And to add a cookie use this:

```cs
filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(myCookie);
```